# Call function from model by passing a variable

Tags: laravel, model

I am approaching Laravel 7, and I am lost in a banality I guess. I create a function in the model that picks up the count of how many posts a category has, then passing the ID parameter.

I call this function in the controller, which then picks up the variable in the views.

It gives me an error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

How can I solve it?

MODEL

```
public function scopeCountActivePostCategory($id)

{
    $query = DB::table('post')->where([
        ['status', 1],
        ['category', $id],
    ]);
    return $query->count();
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
// get details category by slug
        // preleva dettagli categoria by slug
        $detailCat = DB::table('categories')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        // get stories
        $post = DB::table('post')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->where('category', $detailCat->id)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->paginate($set->app_result_x_page);

        return view('category')->with([
            'posts' => $posts, 
            'set' => $set, 
            'totalActivePost' => Post::CountActivePostCategory($detailCat->id),
            'detailCat' => $detailCat
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `get()` in your query. The way you have it, you're trying to count query builder (SQL query string) instead of the collection you would get by putting `get()` on the end of your builder. Change your code to this:

```
public function scopeCountActivePostCategory($id)

{
    $query = DB::table('post')->where([
        ['status', 1],
        ['category', $id],
    ])->get(); //Get here
    return $query->count();
}
```

EDIT

The calling of `CountActivePostCategory` function might be a problem as well. You are calling static function `CountActivePostCategory` but you didn't define it as static in your `Post` model. Change your function to this:

```
public static function countActivePostCategory($id){
  //body
}
```

And then call it in your controller like this:

```
'totalActivePost' => Post::countActivePostCategory($detailCat->id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it gives me the same mistake

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!